# Find position of a node in In-order traversal of complete binary tree in less than O(n)

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, graph-theory

**Question:** Given a node **n** of a complete binary tree. You have three types of information,

1. Number of nodes of the sub-tree rooted in node **n**
2. Parent of node **n**
3. Immediate child of node **n**

Find **n**'s position in the complete binary tree, if it is traversed **in-order**.

**Example:**

```
       0
     /   \
    1     2
   / \   / \
  3   4 5   6
```

For the given tree, position of node 2 is 6 if you consider 1-based indexing. Position of 6 is 7.

**Is it possible to find the answer in less than linear time complexity?**

Comment: I'm assuming that you have this information for *every* node, not just the one given node (that seems to make the problem unsolvable).  The position of a node within its subtree is easy: it's the size of its left subtree, plus one.  You then need to walk to the root, updating the position: if you came from the left subtree, keep the current position, otherwise add the left subtree size plus one.  Runtime is O(depth of node), which on average is O(log(size of tree)).

Comment: The question needs clarification. If you cannot know the parent of the parent node... etc, then it is impossible to solve.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually constant time with bitwise operations! First change `n` to `n+1`. Then remove the most significant bit, multiply by 2, and add 1. Finally multiply by `2^h` where `h=log(x)` and `x` is the information 1. (number of nodes in subtree). This is all done efficiently using bitwise operations.

Example : `2 -> 3 -> 3 -> 6`, `6 -> 7 -> 7 -> 7`, `3 -> 4 -> 1 -> 1` (you have to keep leading zeros)

I have no time now but will post explanation later :)

Comment: You seem to assume that the tree always consists of consecutive numbers. I'm not sure that is given in the question.